# In Three.js, lights don't work

Tags: webgl, three.js

I've been fooling around with Three.js for a while, and I don't seem to be able to get any sort of lights to work.  The scene renders normally with the 0xFFFFFF ambient lighting, but adding lights doesn't have any effect.  I've copied the code directly from the examples and the lights are listed in the children of scene, only not showing up...

```
        var camera;
        var scene;
        var renderer;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.z = 600;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(new THREE.PointLight(0xFF0000, 3.0, 1000));

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            //renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.domElement.id = "canvas";
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            $(window).resize(function() {
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            });
            $("#container").get(0).appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            function Animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            Animate();
        });
```

Comment: post some code for us, please.

Comment: I added it.  Sorry, I had to omit a bunch of parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not give much to work with, but one thing to check is that your materials support lights. That means you should be using `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial`. Also note that if you are using a custom `ShaderMaterial`, it does not magically get scene lighting.

Comment: The issue that I'm having now is that I cannot seem to apply colors to parts with the lighting.  When I add an ambient light, everything in the scene becomes that color, ignoring the color I set the materials.

Comment: Tone down the ambient light or decrease the ambient property of the material. In addition, make sure the other lights have enough color & intensity, also in the material properties.

Comment: I find that if I set the ambient light's color to 0xFFFFFF and set the ambient property of the material to the desired color, I get the desired outcome.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: More or less, just play with the light and material colors; the lighting equation for Lambert material is roughly this: `lightingColor = combinedLightsColors * materialDiffuse + ambientLightColor * materialAmbient + emissive`